# How could I install Torch on Google Colab if it does not exist the file ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bash, deep-learning, torch, google-colaboratory

I want to install Torch (http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html#_) on Google Colab. However, to install Torch, we need to run the following command at the final step `source ~/.bashrc`

To run this command on google colab, the code I use is

```
%%bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

When I run those, I get a warning

> bash: line 1: /content/.bashrc: No such file or directory

I also use this command to find bashrc

```
!find / -name '*bashrc'
```

And here is the output I get

> /root/.bashrc
>
> /etc/skel/.bashrc
>
> /etc/bash.bashrc
>
> /usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc
>
> /usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/skel/dot.bashrc
>
> /usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/bash.bashrc

I try to run the `source` command on all of those paths. I also try the same with `.profile`. But the Torch still has not been installed.

EDIT: I'm not sure if Torch is installed or not. The specific problem here is that I just get an error

> command not found

whenever I run `th` or `luarocks`

Comment: Sourcing that file doesn't install anything, it's meant to update your `PATH`.

Comment: I have installed Torch framework and `source ~/.bashrc` is just the last command to update my profile. But whenever I run that command, I get an error. So I guessed the problem is that there is no `.bashrc` in Google Colab home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the required path and environment by python

```
#for Torch with Lua 5.3:
import os
os.environ['LUA_PATH'] = '/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/root/.luarocks/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/root/torch/install/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/root/torch/install/lib/lua/5.3/?.lua;/root/torch/install/lib/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua'
os.environ['LUA_CPATH'] ='/root/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/root/torch/install/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/root/torch/install/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so;./?.so'
os.environ['PATH'] += ':/root/torch/install/bin'

if 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' not in os.environ.keys():
  os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ''
else:
  os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] += ':'
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] +='/root/torch/install/lib'

if 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH' not in os.environ.keys():
  os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = ''
else:
  os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] += ':'
os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'] +='/root/torch/install/lib'

if 'LUA_CPATH' not in os.environ.keys():
  os.environ['LUA_CPATH'] = ''
else:
  os.environ['LUA_CPATH'] += ';'
os.environ['LUA_CPATH'] += '/root/torch/install/lib/?.so'
```

Comment: It seems Torch has been successfully installed after I run these codes. But I don't really understand what it is doing. Can you explain more about that?

Comment: This didn't work for me... still have an error that luarocks was not found

Comment: @BigTimeStats: be aware of the version of your Lua. You may have to replace all of the '5.3' with your version.

Answer (score 2):

in case this question is still actual, type these commands in Google Colab:`

```
from os import path
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())

accelerator = 'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'

!pip install -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-0.3.0.post4-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl torchvision
import torch
```

Comment: It seems that these commands will install pytorch package instead of the Torch framework.

Comment: You are right. Excuse me, i have not read the question carefully, and I do not know how you could install torch

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Torch starter Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HoJ2qboOanL578Qz_NH3cvV86EfTyhe-) I created with cells to install Torch.