# How to install bash snippet in google colab?

Tags: linux, bash, code-snippets

I want to install a bash program in google colab, I got the instruction to do
nano ~/.bashrc
Then paste the code and save it then
source ~/.bashrc
Now I should be able to run the program anywhere in the session.
But the problem is I tried editing the .bashrc file by moving to txt and pasting and everything imaginable but
program command not found
Error comes. I also tried the torch installation process [How could I install Torch on Google Colab if it does not exist the file ~/.bashrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030306/how-could-i-install-torch-on-google-colab-if-it-does-not-exist-the-file-bashr)
But no success. Can anyone please help.

Comment: How are you executing the command ? try `! source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Yes I'm doing it like !source ~/.bashrc